# Populating a "count matrix" with permutations of R data.table rows

Tags: r, matrix, count, data.table

(For the following, I could either an R data.frame or R data.table. Both are ok.)

I have the following data.table:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(V1=c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat", "bird","bird","bird","bird"), 
                    V2=rep(42, 9), V3=c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 8)) 

> print(dt)
     V1 V2 V3
1:  dog 42  1
2:  dog 42  2
3:  cat 42  4
4:  cat 42  5
5:  cat 42  7
6: bird 42  1
7: bird 42  2
8: bird 42  5
9: bird 42  8
```

Column `V3` contains integers from 1 to 8. My goal is to populate an 8 by 8 zero matrix with the count of each combination "pair" given the unique category in column `V1`

So, the combination pairs for `dog`, `cat`, and `bird` are:

```
dog: (1, 2)
cat: (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 7)
bird: (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (5, 8)
```

For each pair, I add `+1` to the corresponding entry in the zero matrix. For this matrix, `(n, m) = (m, n)`. The matrix given `dt` would be:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1: 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 1
2: 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
3: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4: 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
5: 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
6: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7: 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
8: 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Note that `(1,2)=(2,1)` has a count 2, from the `dog` combination and the `bird` combination.

(1) Is there a method to calculate the combinations of values in an R data.table/data.frame column, given the unique value in another column?

Perhaps it would make sense to output an R list, with vector "pairs", e.g.

```
list(c(1, 2), c(2, 1), c(4, 5), c(4, 7), c(5, 7), c(5, 4), c(7, 4), c(7, 5),
    c(1, 2), c(1, 5), c(1, 8), c(2, 5), c(2, 8), c(5, 8), c(2, 1), c(5, 1),
    c(8, 1), c(5, 2), c(8, 2), c(8, 5))
```

However, I'm not sure how I would use this to populate a matrix...

(2) Given the input data.table/data.frame, what would be the most efficient data-structure to use to write out a matrix, as soon above?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: R can manage fine with a list-of-lists. But in this case we can skip the intermediate tuples/list anyway given we know we're dealing with an 8x8 matrix/data.table, just directly increment the corresponding cell counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a data.table solution that seems to be efficient. We basically doing a self join in order to create combinations and then count. Then, similar to what @coldspeed done with Numpy, we will just update a zero matrix by locations with counts.

```
# a self join
tmp <- dt[dt, 
             .(V1, id = x.V3, id2 = V3), 
             on = .(V1, V3 < V3), 
             nomatch = 0L,
             allow.cartesian = TRUE
          ][, .N, by = .(id, id2)]

## Create a zero matrix and update by locations
m <- array(0L, rep(max(dt$V3), 2L))
m[cbind(tmp$id, tmp$id2)] <- tmp$N
m + t(m)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    0    2    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [2,]    2    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

---

Alternatively, we could create `tmp` using `data.table::CJ` but that could be (potentially - thanks to @Frank for the tip) less memory efficient as it will create all possible combinations first, e.g.

```
tmp <- dt[, CJ(V3, V3)[V1 < V2], by = .(g = V1)][, .N, by = .(V1, V2)]

## Then, as previously
m <- array(0L, rep(max(dt$V3), 2L))
m[cbind(tmp$V1, tmp$V2)] <- tmp$N
m + t(m)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    0    2    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [2,]    2    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

Comment: I guess dcast/acast should be as fast as building and filling m, like eg `dt[, CJ(V3, V3)[V1 < V2], by=.(g = V1)][, reshape2::acast(.SD, factor(V1, 1:8) ~ factor(V2, 1:8), drop=FALSE)]` hm... though I guess that only fills the upper tri (a workaround... `acast(rbind(.SD, .SD[, c(1, 3:2)], use.names = FALSE), ...`).

Comment: @Frank I like your `CJ(V3, V3)[V1 < V2]` modification, it seem to perform faster and be more memory efficient.

Comment: I've just tested on a big data set and the `acast` part takes ages while the zero matrix is instant.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the most elegant approach, but it works:

```
myfun <- function(x, matsize=8) {
    # get all (i,j) pairs but in an unfortunate text format
    pairs_all <- outer(x, x, paste)

    # "drop" all self-pairs like (1,1)
    diag(pairs_all) <- "0 0"

    # convert these text-pairs into numeric pairs and store in matrix
    ij <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(pairs_all, " "), as.numeric))

    # create "empty" matrix of zeros
    mat <- matrix(0, nrow=matsize, ncol=matsize)

    # replace each spot of empty matrix with a 1 if that pair exists
    mat[ij] <- 1

    # return 0/1 matrix
    return(mat)
}

# split your data by group
# lapply the custom function to each group
# add each group's 0/1 matrix together for final result
Reduce('+', lapply(split(dt$V3, dt$V1), myfun))
```

If anyone has a more direct way to implement the first 3 (non-comment) lines of `myfun`, I would happily incorporate them.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you mean `Reduce()`?

Comment: Yes, thank you; I have edited my post.  I had tidyverse loaded (which used purr::reduce) instead of base::Reduce.  I always get myself into trouble when I fail to use a fresh R session to test a possible SO answer.