# Populating a “count matrix” with combinations of pandas DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, count

Let's say I have the following pandas DataFrame in Python3.x

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'name':['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'bird', 'bird', 'bird', 'bird'], 'number':[42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42], 'count':[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 8]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

print(df)
##    name  number  count
## 0   dog      42      1
## 1   dog      42      2
## 2   cat      42      4
## 3   cat      42      5
## 4   cat      42      7
## 5  bird      42      1
## 6  bird      42      2
## 7  bird      42      5
## 8  bird      42      8
```

Column `counts` contains integers from 1 to 8. My goal is to populate an 8 by 8 zero matrix with the count of each combination "pair" given the unique category in column `name`.

So, the combination pairs for `dog`, `cat`, and `bird` are:

```
dog: (1, 2)
cat: (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 7)
bird: (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (5, 8)
```

For each pair, I add `+1` to the corresponding entry in the zero matrix.

This matrix will be symmetric, i.e. `(n, m) = (m, n)`. The matrix given `df` would be:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1: 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 1
2: 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
3: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4: 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
5: 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
6: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7: 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
8: 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Note that `(1,2)=(2,1)` has a count 2, from the `dog` combination and the `bird` combination.

(1) In order to do this, I think it would be best to create a list of "combinations tuples" given the pandas DataFrame.

That is, something like

```
list_combos = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 7), (5, 4), (7, 4), (7, 5),
    (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (5, 8), (2, 1), (5, 1),
    (8, 1), (5, 2), (8, 2), (8, 5)]
```

Given that the matrix is symmetric, perhaps it would be better to use:

```
list_combos2 = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 7), (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (5, 8)]
```

How could one calculate the permutations of entires in a pandas DataFrame, given the categorical value in 'names'?

(2) What would be the most algorithmically efficient (i.e. RAM) to populate this matrix, given the list of tuples?

I should be able to feed a list of tuples into a numpy array, but how does one fill in the zeros?

Comment: Looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811519/populating-a-count-matrix-with-permutations-of-r-data-table-rows?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me. Was just wondering if they were related. Anyway I've already answered you.

Comment: Nowhere did you explain *why* you need an 8x8 matrix instead of list-of-tuples (or possibly faster, an mx2 array). *What do you actually use the 8x8 matrix for later on?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use groupby, iterate over combinations, and build your matrix like so:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

mat = np.zeros((df['count'].max(), ) * 2)
idx = []
for _, g in df.groupby('name'):
    idx.extend(combinations(g['count'] - 1, r=2))

np.add.at(mat, list(zip(*idx)), 1)
mat += mat.T

array([[0., 2., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

There *may* be a faster solution, but this is the cleanest one I can think of.

Comment: Ah, `itertools.combinations` is what I was looking for! I was trying something with `itertools.product`. Thanks!

Comment: beat me to it :) I would also suggest storing the full matrix is worthless as it is symmetric and has no diagonal. In contrast if memory / performance is important store only the top triangle?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Yup, especially for large matrices, since like you mentioned, this is symmetrical. Good point!

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane I agree storing the entire matrix is worthless. How would you revise this? `idx` is really all of the information

Comment: you can keep a a flat 1D list (`idx`). Then use a bit of logic to re-index where necessary.

Comment: @EB2127 Like Alexander says, just extract the upper portion using `mat[np.triu_indices(mat.shape[0])]`.

Comment: You would actually probably not want to instantiate `mat` and just use `np.triu_indices(8)` as a map from `idx` to the matrix representation

Comment: I like the use of `np.add.at`!

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks piR, I like your use of anything. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using Numpy's `bincount`

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for tup in df.itertuples():
    d[tup.name].append(tup.count)

i, j = zip(*chain(*(combinations(v, 2) for v in d.values())))
i, j = np.array(i + j) - 1, np.array(j + i) - 1

np.bincount(i * 8 + j, minlength=64).reshape(8, 8)

array([[0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```